# I want to display value of target to be displayed, but it is showing a compiler error

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, c++17

Here is my code -

```cpp
class Solution {

public:

    int searchInsert(vector<int>& nums, int target) {

        int print(int);

        print(int c){

            cout<<c;
        }

        print(target);        

        return 0;
    }
};
```

Although this is not what i intend to do from my code, I am just facing issue in calling the function, so to make it more simple I wrote this printing function.
Someone please tell me what is wrong here and how to correct it.

Comment: You can't define functions inside other functions. Declaring them (`int print(int);`) is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Lambda functions can be used here, I guess.

```
int fun(int a) {
    auto print = [&](int N) {
        cout << N << '\n';
    };
    print(a);
}
```

This should work for you.

Comment: Is it necessary to capture?